# Issue with Magento Host-Guest VirtualBox configuration - Exception : Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent

Tags: magento-2.1.2

I'm facing an issue with accessing Magento configured with VirtualBox on Windows host. I had freshly installed Magento 2 on Windows 10. I'm using a virtualBox with Ubunto as Guest on it, where I had installed Apache2 with PHP/ MYSQL. I had also moved the Magento2 Database on Ubuntu, (Just Magento folder is on Win 10) But when I access the store through browsers both in Windows & in Ubuntu, it shows following error:-

```
1 exception(s): Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /media/sf_Magento2_2/index.php:20) in /media/sf_Magento2_2/vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/Cookie/PhpCookieManager.php on line 148 Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /media/sf_Magento2_2/index.php:20) in /media/sf_Magento2_2/vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/Cookie/PhpCookieManager.php on line 148 #0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'Cannot modify h...', '/media/sf_Magen...', 148, Array) #1 /media/sf_Magento2_2/vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/Cookie/PhpCookieManager.php(148): setcookie('store', 'default', 1548893731, '/Magento2_2/', '', false, true) #2 /media/sf_Magento2_2/vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/Cookie/PhpCookieManager.php(121): Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager->setCookie('store', 'default', Array) #3 /media/sf_Magento2_2/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreCookieManager.php(61): Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager->setPublicCookie('store', 'default', Object(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PublicCookieMetadata)) #4 /media/sf_Magento2_2/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/Plugin/StoreCookie.php(90): Magento\Store\Model\StoreCookieManager->setStoreCookie(Object(Magento\Store\Model\Store\Interceptor)) #5 /media/sf_Magento2_2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(121): Magento\Store\Model\Plugin\StoreCookie->beforeDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) #6 /media/sf_Magento2_2/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) #7 /media/sf_Magento2_2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) #8 /media/sf_Magento2_2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) #9 /media/sf_Magento2_2/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array) #10 /media/sf_Magento2_2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) #11 /media/sf_Magento2_2/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() #12 /media/sf_Magento2_2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() #13 /media/sf_Magento2_2/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor)) #14 {main}
```

I can access via ftp, the files from both guest & host, so there is no problem with virtualBox configuration. Everything else is OK..

Previously, I had XAMPP (Apache, PHP) before with Magento 2 all installed on windows 10, and it worked fine. It's just with remote virtualBox configuration. I'm getting this issue. Not sure if I'm doing something wrong with configuration.

Any help would me much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Just sorted by myself, I had to change magento url in database on webserver..